# How to call onchange from python xml rpc, for Odoo 15?

Tags: python, odoo

Hello I want to update a MO product_qty field, but keep all the related records (picking/transfers)
synched.

If I write to the record the product_qty gets updated, but not the related record. When doing this manually it works as intended.

I have tried the following, with no success.

```
update = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'mrp.production', 'onchange', [1223,{'product_qty': 10}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do here is more to check in the code what functions are called that have an `@api.onchage` with at least `product_qty` in it.

By quick looking in the model with `_name = 'mrp.production'`, I can see 3 of them. Perhaps some other classes that `'_inherit'` from it can add some, to be verified.

So try this :

```py
update = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'mrp.production', '_onchange_product_qty', [[1223]])
update = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'mrp.production', '_onchange_move_raw', [[1223]])
update = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'mrp.production', '_onchange_move_finished', [[1223]])
```

There is also the possibility (a bit more rare but exists) that another model has an onchange on its `production_id.product_qty` e.g.

Looking at relevant models with the Regex Search `@api\.onchange.*'product_qty'` in both Odoo and Enterprise (if used) can be a good idea ;)

Hope it helps !

Comment: BTW, if you check the def onchange in the base model class, you'll see it needs what fields are changed and the values, it's a really trick place to work tbh, had to play with it some time ago and I advise against that :D

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about checking the model class. Great tip